# Docker Error - Request failed with status code 400 after using host.docker.internal

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, localhost

I am calling localhost api (of host machine) within docker container. After a lot research, I came to know - we need to use host.docker internal in docker compose file in order to call localhost api. below is my setting in docker compose file -

```
extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

here local host api - `http://localhost:39214/`

I am getting error -

> Request failed with status code 400

it means that connection is happening. but still error occurs. I am using windows machine. what I am missing?

Comment: Like you say, 400 is a response sent by your API, so the connection works. If you want help, you need to tell us how you send the request and how the APi responds.

Comment: @HansKilian API call is -  `const appResponse = await axios({
          method: 'post',
          url: apiurl
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': req.headers.authorization,
          },
          data: jsontestdata
        })
          .then(async (r) => {
            return r.data;
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            throw new ApplicationError(
              'Connection to Message Api Failed ' + error.message
            );
          });`  and api url - `http://localhost:39214/api/test`